# Autobahn: Subscribing to channels with regex or wildcard pattern

Tags: autobahn, autobahnws

My question is very simple and straight-forward. In RabbitMQ, we can subscribe to channels using regex or wildcard pattern("Topic" type subscription). So is there any possibility to achieve this in Autobahn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern-based subscriptions are now explained in more detail [in its own document](https://github.com/wamp-proto/wamp-proto/blob/master/rfc/text/advanced/ap_pubsub_pattern_based_subscription.md) which is also referenced from the [WAMP IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-oberstet-hybi-tavendo-wamp-02). Here's an example, quoting from the [current AutobahnJS reference](http://autobahn.ws/js/reference.html#patter-based-subscriptions):

> **Pattern-Based Subscriptions**
>
> As a default, topic URIs in subscriptions are matched exactly.
>
> It is possible to change the matching policy to either prefix or
> wildcard matching via an option when subscribing, e.g.
>
> ```
> session.subscribe('com.myapp', on_event_all, { match: 'prefix' })
> session.subscribe('com.myapp..update', on_event_update, { match: 'wildcard' })
> ```
>
> In the first case, events for all publications where the topic
> contains the prefix `com.myapp` will be received, in the second events
> for all publications which match the wildcard pattern, e.g.
> `com.myapp.user121.update` and `com.myapp.sensor_23.update`.

Given the above example is from official AutobahnJS docs, I presume the crossbar.io WAMP router must also have support built-in now.

As for any other WAMP libraries, your mileage will likely vary.

Answer (score 1):

The [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) specification is split into 2 parts:

1. the [**basic profile**](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/basic.md), which is stable and mandatory for all implementation to implement fully.
2. the [**advanced profile**](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/advanced.md), which is work-in-progress and the features herein are optional for implementations to provide.

[Pattern-based subscriptions](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/advanced.md#pattern-based-subscriptions) are part of the WAMP "Advanced Profile", but **not yet** (2015/01) in the [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) WAMP client libraries or the e.g. the [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/) WAMP router (see [here](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/issues/75)).